# In linear regression, does the t-test of significance satisfy $\sup_{\beta\in\Theta_0}Pr(\textrm{Reject}\ H_0: \beta_j=0)=\alpha$ asymptotically?

Tags: regression, t-test, linear-model, type-i-and-ii-errors

Suppose I have a linear regression $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+U\equiv X'\beta+U$, where $E(U|X)=0$. After we have found the least squares estimator of $\beta\equiv[\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2]$ as $\widehat{\beta}=(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Y}$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is the data matrix for $[1, X_1, X_2]$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ is the data matrix for $Y$. Usually the value of the t-statistic $T=\frac{\widehat{\beta}_j}{se(\widehat{\beta}_j)}$ is reported for each coefficient as significance test for $H_0:\beta_j=0$ for $j=0,1,2$. Suppose the significance level we choose is $\alpha$, resulting in critical value $CV_{\alpha}$ beyond which we reject. Under $H_0$, $T$ is asymptotically $N(0,1)$ and $Pr(\textrm{Reject}\ H_0: \beta_j=0)=Pr(|T|>CV_{\alpha})\approx Pr(|Z|>z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}})=\alpha$, where $z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$. Let $\Theta_0$ be the parameter space for $\beta$ under $H_0$, that is, $\beta_j=0$ and the other two parameters are unrestricted.  Since this rejection probability under $H_0$ does not depend on $\beta$, we have $\sup_{\beta\in\Theta_0}Pr(\textrm{Reject}\ H_0: \beta_j=0)=\alpha$ asymptotically. That is, the type I error is controlled uniformly over the null parameter space.

In addition, let $\sigma=var(U)$, it seems that  $\sup_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\sup_{\beta\in\Theta_0}Pr(\textrm{Reject}\ H_0: \beta_j=0)=\alpha$ asymptotically is also true,where $\Sigma$ is a bounded range. So the typeI error is also controlled uniformly over the nuisance parameter space.

Seems that this conclusion still holds if there are generated regressors, for example, $X_1$ is estimated in an earlier stage as $\widehat{X}_1$.

Does this sound correct? I think it does, because under $H_0$ the t-test is asymptotically standard normal (asymptotically pivotal) and the critical values are prespecified known constants. This means that the rejection probability do not depend on any parameters (whether they are regression coefficients or varaince of the error term).

Comment: For which s.e.s do you claim this reasoning to hold? E.g., when you have heteroskedasticity, it is not true that the default s.e.s yield level $\alpha$ tests.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks!  I guess if I use the heteroskedastic-robust standard error, this will not be a problem. Right?

Comment: Indeed, these will be valid over a larger range of error variace patterns. That said, you can take that reasoning one step further and argue that serial correlation invalidates HC s.e.s, and you'd need to use HAC s.e.s. In other words, one needs to be clear about what $\Sigma$ really means. To say it is a "bounded range" (what that is to mean is also not quite clear to me in any case) does not seem enough to me. And even then, establishing uniformity can be quite tricky in my experience, so I would not easily dare to confirm claims in that direction.